# unable to update the Set property

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

```
var npm = require("npm")
var immutable = require("immutable");
var test = immutable.fromJS

const a = test({name:true,b:[]})
console.log(a);
a.set('name',false);

console.log("------------");
console.log(a.get('name')) // gives still value true.
```

what is the expected value of the last console ? I thought it would be true .Can Someone help me where I went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` isn't reassigned. `a.set` returns a new object.

```js
const a = Immutable.fromJS({name:true,b:[]})
console.log(a);
const newA = a.set('name',false);

console.log("------------");
console.log(a.get('name'));
console.log(newA.get('name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The point of Immutable.js is that the objects you get from it **are immutable** (cannot be changed). Operations that look like mutator operations *return a new object*. So:

```
a = a.set('name', false);
```

From [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set):

> **`set()`**
>
> Returns a **new Map** also containing the new key, value pair. If an equivalent key already exists in this Map, it will be replaced.

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: Thanks, Simple one